# Orchard CMS Database foreign keys

Tags: orchardcms

Why there is no foreign keys in Orchard CMS Database?

I mean, when to tables are linked by a column, why no foreign are created to shield the relation?

Comment: Orchard uses NHibernate, which handles the foreign keys in code rather then in the database itself

Comment: And what about the performance of not having foreign keys?